# REGEX must include substring

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the word: <*hasburnt*> in the string below using the this regex: `<\*.*(bur).*\*>`

But it gives me both <*hasburnt*> <*electrical*>.  How do I just get <*hasburnt*> ?

> bench testedstarter, starter just makes noise, and <*hasburnt*>
>   <*electrical*> smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `/<.*?(bur).*?>/`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xkDuGt/1)

The reason for `?` here is because `.*` tries to match as much characters as possible, so it also matches `<electrical`. `.*?` makes it *lazy* - trying to match as little as possible, and as such ending the match at `<hasburnt>`.

EDIT: using `?` for the first `.*` would make `<hasburnt>` independent of positions of similar strings.

Comment: maybe even <.*?(bur).*?>, in case of <electrical> <hasburnt>

Comment: @NicolasBudig You're right, thanks. Edited.

Comment: The original string has * after the <.